# Run iOS project UT's using fastlane scan on Apple M1

Tags: ios, cocoapods, gitlab-ci-runner, apple-m1, fastlane

We are setting up CI/CD for iOS project using Gitlab & fastlane tools on Mac Mini(M1 Chip).

When there is a new pull request created, pipeline starts and it executes below command success.

- fastlane ios build

But it shows "no such module 'Alamofire'" error for below command.

- fastlane ios test

Other observations on same build machine Mac Mini(M1 Chip):

- It shows same errors "no such module 'Alamofire'" when try to build or run tests using Xcode(Uncheck Open using Rosetta).
- Both build & run tests works fine with Xcode(Check Open using Rosetta).

We are looking for build the iOS project and run unit tests on simulator for new/update pull request. Build works fine but run unit tests fails during compilation.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Just want to add one simple alternative for anybody who may be constrained on their ability to get an update to one of their projects dependencies.   I recently just worked through this issue and found that I needed to specify the xcode build command to use.  For some reason fastlane build works fine, but for fastlane scan this seems to be required to force running with Rosetta.

```
xcodebuild_command: "env NSUnbufferedIO=YES arch -x86_64 xcodebuild"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using cocoapods to import Alamofire right?

Do you happen to have any `post_install` steps that are setting build_settings in your podfile?

Comment: That's right, using cocoapods to import Alamofire.

Have below lines in Podilfe at the end.

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
  end

end

Comment: I tried removing post_install script, it is giving different error. We have video chat framework integrated in the project. Error says, building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS.

Comment: Used .xcframework instead of .framework for compilation. It worked. Thank you.